# Estoy intentando añadir objetos a una lista en JavaScript pero me devuelve [object Object] [object Object]

Tags: javascript, html, html5, formularios, javascript-objeto

Tengo un formulario de checkbox y guardo los valores en una lista. Como se muestra en el siguiente código:

```
    <div >
            <input type="checkbox" id="p1" name="pat" value="Diabetes"> Diabetes
            <br>            
                        
            <input type="checkbox" id="p2" name="pat" value="HA"> Hipertensión Arterial
            <br>
            
            <input type="checkbox" id="p3" name="pat" value="EPOC"> EPOC
            <br>
    
            <input type="checkbox" id="p4" name="pat" value="Enfermedad Inf. Intestinal/ Patología Digestiva"> Enfermedad Inf. Intestinal/ Patología Digestiva
            <br><br>
    
    
            <button  onclick ="datos()">datos</button>
            
            
        </div>
    <script>
    function datos(){
                arr = $('[name="pat"]:checked').map(function(){    
                return this.value;
                })
                .get();
        
                var str = arr.join(',');
                
                console.log(arr);
            }
    </script>
```

Lugo recorro esa lista para que cada valor de esa lista se guarde en un objeto distinto, y a la vez cada objeto se guarda en una lista, es decir la lista contiene todos los objetos. No se si los objetos los añado bien ya que la lista me sale [object Object].

```
var l = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        var lista = {
            nombre: arr[i],
            paciente: IDPaciente
        }
        l += lista;
        console.log("l", JSON.stringify(l));
    }
```

Comment: ¿Difiere esta pregunta de [esta otra](/q/520368)? ¿O esta vez no es en una tabla?

Comment: No es en una tabla

Comment: ¿Probaste hacer directamente `console.log(JSON.stringify(l));`?

Comment: Si, lo probé y me devolvia "[object Object]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La variable `l` la has predefindo como una variable del tipo **array**, y no como un *string*, por lo tanto debes cambiar esto:

```
l += lista;
```

por esto:

```
l.push(lista);
```

pues el método [push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) agrega contenidos a una variable de tipo **array**.

Como curiosidad tambien te muestro otro tipo de sintaxis equivalente al push, que seria este:

```
l[l.length] = lista;
```

mediante el cual asignas al siguiente número de indice (representado por el número de elementos del array) el valor de `lista`.

Aquí te dejo un snippet de ejemplo donde lo he puesto todo junto pero para que veas que funciona bien:

```js
function datos() {
  arr = $('[name="pat"]:checked').map(function() {
      return this.value;
    })
    .get();

  var str = arr.join(',');

  console.log(arr);

  let IDPaciente = "test"

  var l = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var lista = {
      nombre: arr[i],
      paciente: IDPaciente
    }
    l.push(lista);
    console.log("l", JSON.stringify(l));
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="p1" name="pat" value="Diabetes"> Diabetes
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="p2" name="pat" value="HA"> Hipertensión Arterial
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="p3" name="pat" value="EPOC"> EPOC
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="p4" name="pat" value="Enfermedad Inf. Intestinal/ Patología Digestiva"> Enfermedad Inf. Intestinal/ Patología Digestiva
  <br><br>
  <button onclick="datos()">datos</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias. Justo era eso, no caí en el método